# Proving statements about a family of functions F generated by ex−1 and ln(x+1) and two closure axioms

Tags: functions

this is a question i got in an exam and the marks distribution for the 4 parts is as $[5+5+15+5]$

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a class of functions from $[0,\infty]$ to $[0,\infty]$ with the following properties:

- the functions $f_1(x) = e^x - 1$ and $f_2(x) = \ln(x+1)$ are in $\mathcal{F}$.
- if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ (not necessarily distinct) are in $\mathcal{F}$, then the functions $f(x) +g(x)$ and $f(g(x))$ are in $\mathcal{F}$.
- if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are in $\mathcal{F}$ and $f(x) \geqslant g(x)$ for all $x \in [0,\infty)$, then $f(x)-g(x)$ is in $\mathcal{F}$.

$(a)$ For any positive integer $n$, show that $h(x) = nx$ is in $\mathcal{F}$.

$(b)$ if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are in $\mathcal{F}$, show that the functions $\ln(f(x)+1)$ and $\ln(g(x)+1)$ are in $\mathcal{F}$.

$(c)$ if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are in $\mathcal{F}$, show that the function $f(x)g(x) + f(x) + g(x)$ is in $\mathcal{F}$.

$(d)$ if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are in $\mathcal{F}$, show that the function $f(x)g(x)$ is in $\mathcal{F}$.

my attempt

for the first part i had taken $f_1(f_2(x)) = e^{\ln(x+1)}-1 = x+1-1 = x$. Now as $x \in \mathcal{F}$, i can just sum it over $n$ times to get that $h(x) = nx$ is in $\mathcal{F}$.

for the second part i just need to take $f_2(f(x))$ and $f_2(g(x))$, that also i did.

i am not sure about third and fourth part. The way i did the is like, for the fourth part,

we know $f_2(x) = \ln(x+1) \in \mathcal{F}$ then $f_2(x) + f_2(x)$ will also $\in \mathcal{F}$ (from second property).

$\Rightarrow 2*\ln(x+1) \in \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow p(x)= \ln(x+1)^2 \in \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow f_1(p(x)) = e^{\ln(x+1)^2}-1 = x^2+2x +1 -1  =x^2+2x \in \mathcal{F}$

as we know $2x \in \mathcal{F}$ because $nx \in \mathcal{F}$ and we knoe $x^2 + 2x \geqslant 2x$ in $[0,\infty) \Rightarrow x^2+2x-2x = x^2 = q(x)\in \mathcal{F}$.

as $f(x)$ and $g(x) \in \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow f(x)+g(x) \in \mathcal{F}$ then $q(f(x) +g(x)) = f(x)^2+g(x)^2+2f(x)g(x) \in \mathcal{F}$ also $q(f(x)) = f(x)^2$ and $q(g(x)) = g(x)^2 \in \mathcal{F}$

now as $f(x)^2+g(x)^2+2f(x)g(x) \geqslant f(x)^2+g(x)^2 $ in $x \in[o,\infty) \Rightarrow2f(x)g(x) \in \mathcal{F}$

now if i take $f_1(f_2(x/2)) = e^{\ln(x/2)+1}-1 = x/2 =r(x) \in \mathcal{F}$

$r(2f(x)g(x)) = f(x)g(x) \in \mathcal{F}$

and for the third part we just add these three functions up to get the answer.

the way i did (if it is correct) feels very crude and brute forced also due to the fact the the third part was for 15 marks but i did the fourth part in the long way and did the third part in just a line. Could someone think of a better way to do this. it will be very helpful thanks:)

Comment: I'd advise to revise the title of the question to something that makes it descriptive, something like "Proving statements about a family of functions $\mathcal F$ generated by $e^x-1$ and $\ln(x+1)$ and two closure axioms"; this gives an idea of what the problem you're working on is, rather than the title looking like a cry for help.

Comment: sorry i will keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your working for (a) and (b) look fine to me.

For (c), you can use the result from (b); if $f(x),g(x)\in\mathcal F$, then $\ln(f(x)+1)$ and $\ln(g(x)+1)$ are both in $\mathcal F$, and their sum $\phi(x):=\ln[(f(x)+1)(g(x)+1)]$ is also in $\mathcal F$. Now, just notice that since $f_1,\phi\in\mathcal F$, we have $(f_1\circ \phi)(x)=e^\phi(x)-1=f(x)g(x)+f(x)+g(x)$ is also in $\mathcal F$. $_\square$

For (d), you're supposed to use the result of (c) and the second condition given for the construction of $\mathcal F$. If $f,g\in\mathcal F$, we have both $fg+f+g$ and $f+g$ in $\mathcal F$ and since $f,g$ are non-negative valued maps, we have $fg+f+g\ge f+g$, hence their difference $fg$ is also in $\mathcal F$

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. :)